# ROS indigo and opencv seems not to work correctly

Tags: opencv, pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to check if I could use opencv with ROS Indigo and also with PCL 1.7, based on this tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials), and it seems there would open a window to show the Image, but nothing happens in my Cmakelists.txt I added find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) and target_link_libraries(xxx xxx ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}).
I also tried with another packages that I found to work I a project, but also happen something similar, when I need to show an image sometimes appear a window, but with nothing inside and starts to turning to black, I think that some programms were made based in ROS hydro, so it's not easy that works with ROS Indigo isn't?

Than you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232768/ros-indigo-and-opencv-seems-not-to-work-correctly/) by [soichirutk](https://answers.ros.org/users/22075/soichirutk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The node in your link subscribes to a topic and displays the images. If the topic doesn't exist or there are no images, it will not display anything.

You should check:

- that you have an image publisher running (camera driver or rosbag playback)
- that you can view the images with rqt_image_view
- that the topic name on your opencv subscriber is correctly mapped to the topic that your image publisher is using.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soichirutk](https://answers.ros.org/users/22075/soichirutk/) on 2016-04-25**:
Yes, you are right what for me seems something strange is that the constructor of the class might "open" a cv::namewindow, or with ROS is different, because in OpenCV if you just create a cv::namewindow it appears and  you can load a Image or just it will be there. I really appreciate your answer